# Is it possible to load script file to illustrator in a programmatical way?

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-illustrator

Currently, what I did is

[image]

What I want to achieve is to load the script file without clicking file menu > scripts and click scripts.

Does anybody encounter this?
It is my pleasure if someone knows. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut or make an icon with path to what you want to do. What I mean is, you are executing an .exe file inside the application, so just find where it is located and make a Direct Access. In case this is not what you expect, notify me.

Answer (score 0):

Well all your scripts will go inside File menu. If you want you can keep your scripts at any location on your machine. And use first line in your script as

```
#target illustrator
```

So whenever you double click the file, script will launch in Illustrator and in case Illustrator is not open it will ask you to open the Illustrator. And if Illustrator is already open script will execute and perform its task. You can use Adobe Extended toolkit to execute the script
Hope this help.